# Functional Banana Traveller - putting together Behavior t GameState

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

The problem is that I do not know how to create the Behavior of type `Behavior t GameState`

I have more code, but am trying to just show what I think is neccessary to talk about the problem. Let me know if there are blanks to be filled in. Here's what I have :

```
data GameState = GameState {agent    :: Agent
                           ,universe :: Universe
                           }

type Universe = Gr Planet ()

data Command = Move PlanetName
             | Look
             | Quit
                 deriving Show

data PlayerCommand = PlayerCommand Command PID
                   | Null
                       deriving Show

updateGS :: PlayerCommand -> GameState -> GameState
updateGS (PlayerCommand (Move planet) pid) gs =
   let agent = getAgent pid gs
       nodes = labNodes $ universe gs
       current = location agent
       Just fromP = lookup (fromEnum current) nodes
       Just toP   = lookup (fromEnum planet) nodes
       fromNode = fromEnum current
       toNode = fromEnum planet
       uPlayer = Player pid (getPlanetName toP) (Location planet)
       mData = MoveData uPlayer (toNode,toP) (fromNode,fromP) nodes
       uPlanets = updateLNodeList mData
   in GameState uPlayer (mkGraph uPlanets $ labUEdges gates

initialGS :: GameState
initialGS = GameState initPlayer (makeUniverse makePlanetNodes)
```

and the event network

```
makeNetworkDescription :: AddHandler PlayerCommand -> IO EventNetwork
makeNetworkDescription addCommandEvent = compile $ do
   eInput <- fromAddHandler addCommandEvent
   let bCommand = stepper Null eInput
   eCommandChanged <- changes bCommand
   let bGameState :: Behavior t GameState
       bGameState = stepper initialGS 
   reactimate $ (\n -> appendFile "output.txt" ("Command is " ++ show n)) <$> eCommandChanged
```

I believe bGameState needs to use eCommandChange, but I run into a problem with the types

```
stepper :: a -> Event t a -> Behavior t a
```

this leads me to believe I need to transform `eInput :: Event t PlayerCommand` into a 
`eGameState :: Event t GameState`, which I can use with `stepper` to make the `Behavior t GameState`

So, My questions are, is my line of thinking correct? If not, could I be re-directed? If so, what would `eGameState :: Event t GameState` look like?

In response to the response below. When I considered `accumB` initially, I saw a type error in the making. Which is what happened when I tried your suggestion.

```
let bGameState :: Behavior t GameState
    bGameState = accumB initialGS $ updateGS <$ eInput
```

yields the error

```
 Couldn't match expected type `GameState'
             with actual type `PlayerCommand'
 Expected type: GameState -> GameState
   Actual type: PlayerCommand -> GameState -> GameState
 In the first argument of `(<$)', namely `updateGS'
 In the second argument of `($)', namely `updateGS <$ eInput'
```

Not sure what to do about that. I'll look at your examples and see if the answer becomes clear. Thanks for poiting out `accumB` was the right way to go, as I was focused on `stepper`

The more I study the suggested code, the more I am puzzled by the type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you need to create an event which remembers a `GameState` and applies the `updateGS` function to it to create a new one. That's the purpose of the function `accumE` and its cousin `accumB`. In particular, you can write

```
bGameState = accumB initialGS $ updateGS <$> eInput
```

To learn more about this pattern, have a look at the examples on the [examples pages](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana/Examples), in particular the Counter.hs and TwoCounters.hs examples.

---

Another point worth mentioning is that I recommend to avoid the `changes` function unless you are dealing with low-level framework stuff. As noted in the documentation, it has several restrictions; the nastiest restriction being that the value is not available until the `reactimate` are executed. You can easily make an infinite loop that way, its purpose is really very narrow.

In your case, the `bCommand` seems superfluous anyway, you have `eCommandChanged = eInput`.

Morale: Turning an event into a behavior is easy, but there is no way back.

Comment: I changed `(<$)` to `(<$>)` but it needs to be approved.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get any message about your edit, but I just changed it myself.